# Why is this group called "The Holomorph of a group"

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, terminology

Many years ago I found in google the notation "Holomorph of group". It is the semi direct product of $G$ with $Aut(G)$. Why is the term "Holomorph" used here, while it is usually used for complex analytic functions? More information on this object is very appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about holomorph groups, but it's probably a word of Greek origin, meaning something like "complete form", "completely formed" or so..

Comment: One nice way to consider the holomorph is as the normalizer of the left regular representation in the group of permutations of elements.

Comment: according to Wikipedia, the name holomorph was introduced by Briot and Bouquet --- http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not a history expert, but according to Miller, Blichfeldt and Dickson: "Theory and applications of finite groups" (1916), footnote p. 46: "The concept of holomorph was used by many early writers, but the term was introduced by W. Burnside in the first edition of his Theory of Groups, 1897, p. 228."

Comment: Yes, what was introduced by the people Carlos Beenakker mentions was the term "holomorphic function" ( at least according to Wikipedia).